# How to host a static web page on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have created a simple one-page responsive design demo website that I want to test across all major devices. I want to change my website design on my local machine and then deploy it to Heroku so I can test my website on a public website across multiple devices.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create new directory
2. Create index.html in new directory
3. Create index.php (Prompts Heroku to deploy index.html as a php app) using `touch index.php`
4. `git init`
5. `git add index.php`
6. `git add index.html`
7. `git commit -m "Your comments..."`
8. `heroku create`
9. `git push heroku master`
10. Open the url for your new Heroku app and view your static website on any device

To test new changes to your local website, repeat steps 6, 7, 9 and 10.

Advantages: 1) It takes less than a minute to deploy your site on the public web via Heroku; 2) It's free.

Comment: One step you can add between `6` and `7` is disable `PHP` on Heroku (if you are not using it), just doing `echo "php_flag engine off" > php.ini`.